# How do I store total points after user input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding my first JavaScript create your own adventure game. I have an input field for the user to enter his actions, a button to submit the action and an output text field for the story. When the button is clicked it starts a function to calculate the effectiveness of the user action.

Each action has a certain amount of points (25, 50, 75). If the user reaches 100 points after a few tries, he wins. If he reaches over 100 he loses. As long as 100 points aren't met, the user may keep on trying different actions.

The problem is that the function needs to store the current total points in a global variable, but it doesn't do that. After every button click the `check` function checks if the 100 points are met and gives hints to the user. But right now, it just says "You did it!" which is what it says when you meet 100 total points. What am I doing wrong?

I'm a total beginner at JavaScript, so I hope my code isn't a complete mess. Any help and advice is welcome. :)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<label>Enter your answer here:</label>
<input id="userInput" type="text" name="userInput">
<input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="Click!" onclick="userAction()">
<textarea id="txtOutput" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="txtOutput">
</textarea>
</fieldset>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

txtOutput.value = "(\This is just a test and not the actual game.\) \n\nChoose your method to convince the merchant: \n\nA. compliment him on his work \nB. bribe him with money \nC. initmidate him \nD. blackmail him";

var totalPoints = 0;

function add(points) {
  totalPoints += points;
}

window.userAction = function() {
  var input = userInput.value.toUpperCase();
  var compliment = "A";
  var bribe = "B";
  var intimidate = "C";
  var blackmail = "D";

    if (input == compliment) {
        add(25);
    }
    else if (input == bribe) {
        add(25);
    }
    else if (input == intimidate) {
        add(50);
    }
    else if (input == blackmail) {
        add(75);
    }
    else {
        txtOutput = "Method not found. Choose either A, B, C or D.";
    }
    check();
}

    window.check = function() {
    if (totalPoints <= 25) {
        txtOutput.value = "You have his attention. Keep going.";
        userAction();
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 50) {
        txtOutput.value = "It's working. Keep going. Don't push it too hard, though.";
        userAction();
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 75) {
        txtOutput.value = "You almost convinced him. Be careful now!";
        userAction();
    }
    else if (totalPoints = 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You did it!";
    }
    else if (totalPoints > 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You pushed it too hard. The merchant runs away!";
    }
    else {
        txtOutput.value = "input not found.";
    }
}
```

The [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Isoldhe/0mo7peoc/3/)

Comment: first I suggest you drop all the `window.` bits, when you're in the "global" space in the browser that's implied

Comment: With your fiddle I'm getting the error "Maximum call stack exceeded" in the console.

Comment: I removed them, although it doesn't fix the function. I added the window. parts because I had some problems earlier with the functions not responding at all without them. Doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Comment: remove calls to userAction(); from window.check event handler

Comment: See my answer & https://jsfiddle.net/0mo7peoc/7/

Comment: You should select the answer you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your calls to UserAction from within window.check

it is calling the same action multiple times and hence you get you did it on first click

change this

```
window.check = function() {
    if (totalPoints <= 25) {
        txtOutput.value = "You have his attention. Keep going.";
        userAction();
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 50) {
        txtOutput.value = "It's working. Keep going. Don't push it too hard, though.";
        userAction();
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 75) {
        txtOutput.value = "You almost convinced him. Be careful now!";
        userAction();
    }
    else if (totalPoints == 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You did it!";
    }
    else if (totalPoints > 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You pushed it too hard. The merchant runs away!";
    }
    else {
        txtOutput.value = "input not found.";
    }
```

to this

```
    window.check = function() {
    if (totalPoints <= 25) {
        txtOutput.value = "You have his attention. Keep going.";

    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 50) {
        txtOutput.value = "It's working. Keep going. Don't push it too hard, though.";
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 75) {
        txtOutput.value = "You almost convinced him. Be careful now!";

    }
    else if (totalPoints = 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You did it!";
    }
    else if (totalPoints > 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You pushed it too hard. The merchant runs away!";
    }
    else {
        txtOutput.value = "input not found.";
    }
}
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0mo7peoc/15/

also change this line

> else if (totalPoints = 100) {

to this

> else if (totalPoints == 100) {

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is you are re-invoking userAction() & with your equality setting vs checking:

```
// Notice here you check `<=`
 else if (totalPoints <= 75) {
    txtOutput.value = "You almost convinced him. Be careful now!";
}
// Notice here you SET `=`, this should be `===`
// this will ALWAYS be true
else if (totalPoints = 100) {
    txtOutput.value = "You did it!";
}
// Notice here you check `>`
else if (totalPoints > 100) {
    txtOutput.value = "You pushed it too hard. The merchant runs away!";
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/0mo7peoc/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

https://jsfiddle.net/exa2k8vq/1/

You had 2 errors:

1. `else if (totalPoints = 100)` while you need `==`
2. you called userAction() in your if, so player got point twice

Answer (score 0):

Only wrong condition is `totalPoints = 100` change it to `totalPoints == 100`. But the actual reason you are getting this behavior is your `check` method. In each of your condition, you are calling `userAction` method again and again. This is why you reach to the conclusion at once.

I have made the adjustment to your fiddle to fix this issue. See updated fiddle [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0mo7peoc/6/)

Update your `check` method to

```
window.check = function() {
    if (totalPoints <= 25) {
        txtOutput.value = "You have his attention. Keep going.";
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 50) {
        txtOutput.value = "It's working. Keep going. Don't push it too hard, though.";
    }
    else if (totalPoints <= 75) {
        txtOutput.value = "You almost convinced him. Be careful now!";
    }
    else if (totalPoints == 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You did it!";
    }
    else if (totalPoints > 100) {
        txtOutput.value = "You pushed it too hard. The merchant runs away!";
    }
    else {
        txtOutput.value = "input not found.";
    }
```

**Note:** I have removed calls to your `userAction` method from this method.

Answer (score -1):

You simply mistyped equals operator, `==`.

```
...
else if (totalPoints == 100) { 
    txtOutput.value = "You did it!"; 
}
```

Comment: He also has extra 'userAction' invocations